# Debugar classes instanciadas no Magento

Tags: php, magento

No `PHP` existem métodos `get_object_vars` e `get_class` que retornam informações sobre a classe, no Magento podemos usar `Zend_Debug::dump()`, o `Mage::log()` e até o [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) do `PHP`, mas durante o desenvolvimento de módulos no Magento, onde precisamos sobrescrever alguma parte do painel administrativo, para isso temos que procurar pelas classes corretas.

Como fazer para obter a lista de todas as classes instanciadas ao acessar uma página do Magento?

Exemplo: O usuário `X` acessou `Catálogo->Atributo->Gerenciar Atributo`, como gerar um Debug com a lista de todas as classes que foram instanciadas quando o usuário acessou a página `Gerenciar Atributo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei 2 soluções para o meu problema

1º Existe `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getModelInstance`

```
public function getModelInstance($modelClass='', $constructArguments=array())
    {
        $className = $this->getModelClassName($modelClass);
        if (class_exists($className)) {
            Varien_Profiler::start('CORE::create_object_of::'.$className);
            $obj = new $className($constructArguments);
            Varien_Profiler::stop('CORE::create_object_of::'.$className);
            return $obj;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

pode usar esse método para encontrar todas as classes instanciadas. Por [ProxiBlue](http://www.proxiblue.com.au/)

2º Adicionar

```
 <pre>
<?php htmlspecialchars( print_r( get_included_files() )); ?>
</pre>
```

No final do `arquivo.php` . Isso imprimir cada arquivo incluído por Magento para um determinado pedido, e desde que os arquivos do Magento são nomeados de forma consistente você pode derivar os nomes de classe. Por [Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/)